# Synchronized ArrayList editing in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have multiple threads of the same kind that are sharing the ArrayList:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> Terminate_List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This ArrayList needs to be updated. I need to delete a single item of that list. The problem is when I reach the line

```
Terminate_List.remove(k);
```

The other thread already deleted another Item of the list, the size has decremented and I get a IndexOutOfBoundsException. So my plan was to make this method synchronized so that only one thread at a time can execute this method. The method is executed by a timer. How can I really let only one thread at a time execute this method?

```
    public synchronized void update_list(){

   for (int k = 0; k < Terminate_List.size(); k++) {

        if (Terminate_List.get(k) == this_ID){

            Terminate_List.remove(k); }}}
```

Comment: Use a static variable and put the update_list() in a loop if the static variable boolean is true then it is checked out if false then make the update.

Comment: You should synchronize all updates to the list against the same object. We can't tell if this is the case because we don't know where `update_list()` is.

Comment: good idea! But can someone tell me why the synchronized doesnt work?

Comment: @brso05 I'm sorry but that's a horrible idea. It is wrong but its failure won't be immediately apparent because it will work most of the time.

Comment: @Hydrophilia The probable reason is that you have several instances of whichever class `update_list()` is in. Without seeing more code it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: @biziclop What do you mean by synchronize all updates to the list against the same object? Do you maybe have an example for me or can show me how I can fix it the way you mean?

Comment: Or even better: use a proper collection that supports concurrency. For `List`, you have [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). But IMO it would be better using another approach for your problem like a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: `public synchronized void foo() {...}` is just a synonym of `public void foo() {synchronized(this) {...}}`. So in your code you're synchronizing against `this`. But your list is in a static variable, from which I assume that you have multiple instances of the class that share this variable (which is a bad idea in itself but that's a different story). All of these instances will synchronize to `this` but of course for all these instances `this` will mean a different object. Therefore they won't stop each other from running.

Comment: Seems like synchronized (terminateList) {
      // ...
  } works but you are saying that sharing a list between threads is the wrong way. Why?

Comment: @Hydrophilia The problem isn't sharing a list between threads but relying on a `static` field to do so. It feels like a code smell, that is a possible indicator of poor design. It looks very much like a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [`remove` by index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) - use [`remove` by reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)). This way you don't have to worry about indexes at all.

Also, `Terminate_List` is static, while your method is not. That means if you have multiple instances of your class, blocking will only occur where two threads area accessing the same instance. To block other threads from updating `Terminate_List`, you need to update how you're using synchronized.

Your code would become this:

```
public void update_list(){
   // your previous impl was equivalent to synchronized(this)
   synchronized (Terminate_List) {  
       Terminate_List.remove((Integer)this_ID);
   }
}
```

Note - I'm assuming `this_ID` is defined as an `int` - if it's already an `Integer` then you don't need the cast (and you'd have a problem with your equality check in your original code).

Comment: Since the list contains `Integer`s, and `this_ID` is probably an `int`, an explicit cast would be needed here.

Comment: There's no mention in the question on what `this_ID` is; though based on the OP using `==` for comparison instead of `equals`, you're probably right. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you have multiple instances of whatever class `update_list()` is in and a static list that is used by them all. If this true, then you need to synchronize using the list as monitor:

```
public void update_list() {
  synchronized (terminateList) {
      // ...
  }
}
```